# Determine If Current View is a Specific Activity

Tags: android, if-statement, android-intent, android-context

I am wanting to set an intent on a logo in the titleBar of my application to go back to the main entry screen when clicked unless of course we are already at that screen. How do I go about checking this in an if statement?

Comment: Where are you setting the "onClick" programmatically or from layout xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I don't understand you correctly, you should just be able to check the class:

```
if(getClass() == MainActivity.class){

}
```

Try that and see if it works.

Comment: No, this did not work. Maybe I should mention that I am using this inside a class MyActivity that all my activities extend.

Comment: I retract that. It did work, I just had the if statement set up wrong. Thanks.